# Why is the Flask element in my HTML not working?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am transferring data from a python sheet to an HTML page using Flask. However, the corresponding code in the HTML file is not even changing color as it is supposed to, I don't think it's registering it as valid code. It is just treating the code as a string and outputting the code on the screen.

Here is the Python code in app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

name = ("Rachel", "Lola")

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def data():
    return render_template(Visualization.html, name=name)
```

Here is the HTML code that's in a file called Visualization.html:

```
  {% for element in name %}
  <p>{{element}}</p>  
  {% endfor %}
```

Any ideas on how to make this transfer the data properly? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your html file should look like this,if you are new to web dev, you should know that every html file should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Your title</title>
    
</head>
<body>
  {% for element in name %}
  <p>{{element}}</p>  
  {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an error in the python file... you should type it as follow

`return render_template('Visualization.html', name=name)`